# deployment of tomcat gives fail to run error

Tags: java, tomcat

When I try to run Tomcat through Netbeans I get:

> Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed,
>   /Users/Dropbox/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/catalina.sh and related
>   scripts are executable.

the line the error directs me to is :

> < nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false"
>   forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>

when i run this code with it broken up the error is on  `forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"`

Catalina.sh is in that file location. I do not know how to check if it is executable. I was working earlier, then it stopped working, but I'm not sure when or what i changed.

Comment: whats in the server logs?

Comment: i do not know how do i find that

Comment: your cataline.sh should be in bin folder, so in parallel to bin there is log folder. Check the files under the logs folder, you may see an exception.

Comment: i do not have either of those how do i add them

Comment: I think it should be Catalina.out, check this image https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8_nB0chWBa64JfKzUwvSrsdo-qQANB2ku49vCZQVRDenSHiN_ssl3CoDeYlQqsSs3hhJ4Hq1oUJxS3B8KeqzSoQYXx9804QXK44Y2VCFh5GfVjGpJd7fdVQlavM8G5QpO8ywnXX3_Mh1=w647-h172-nc

Answer (score -1):

Your server is not getting deployed and localhost isn't running.So,try to attach the server again to the application while running the project. Quite the same problem occurred to me while I was working with Tomcat in Eclipse.
Hope you find your answer here.